# GET/POST variable not set in netbeans IDE

Tags: netbeans

I dunno if its a silly mistake but a post/get variable is not being set, while it is supposed to be. Here are the HTML and php code snippets:

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>
        Chain Story
    </title>
</head>
<body>
    <form method="GET" action="check-valid.php">
        <textarea name="a" rows="5" cols="50"></textarea>
        <input type="submit" value="Add" />
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

check-valid.php:

```
<?php
    require 'includes/connect.inc.php';

    $conn_ref = connect_db('chainstory') or die(mysqli_error());

    if(isset($_GET)){
        echo 'Get variable set';
        if(isset ($_GET['a'])){
            $as = $_GET['a'];
            $query = "insert into story1 values (1, " . $as . ")";
            mysql_query($query, $conn_ref);
    }

    else{
        echo $_GET;
    }}

?>
```

I get the following output:

```
Get variable set
Notice: Array to string conversion in /home/kevin/Code/php/myWebsite/check-valid.php on line 15
Array
```

I am coding this in netbeans. Can anyone point me out what mistake im making? :(

Comment: First, please replace `echo $_GET;` to `var_dump($_GET)` and see the output.

Comment: This is the output now!`Get variable setarray(0) { }`

Comment: @Kovge Works after moving it to a new folder and edited with gedit. I dunno wat's wrong with netbeans.

Comment: If the netbeans was wrong, there can be problem if you did not save, or netbeans showd the file is saved, but was not... The running of the code, does not depends your ide.

Comment: i tried changing the variable names constantly and viewed those files separately using raw text editors... I don't think the files wer not saved!

Answer (score 0):

Did you try rename the textarea? Longer name , and give id to textarea same the name.

What browser does you use for testing?
I met some problems with input names in `IE` for example if an input name matches a javascript function name or protected names. Have you a javascript function or variable in your code what's name is `a` ? Because if the name of the input conflicts with a js var or name IE does not send the input field to the server. (Chrome Firefox and other browsers does)

Comment: Well, just now i moved those files into a new folder and it works like a charm now! I don't know what is wrong with netbeans - php. Already, I faced such a problem a while back with netbeans php....

Comment: I think it is not depends on your IDE, but php version and Browser.